# Use of Dictionary<ThreadingTimer, Label> in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, timer

How can use  Dictionary in ThreadingTimer?I want to use a timer that show the amount of row update in per 2sec and also showed in label in windows form.Here is my code,

```
ThreadingTimer timer;

private Dictionary<ThreadingTimer, Label> dict = new Dictionary<ThreadingTimer, Label>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string myconstring = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=alicosms;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;";
   MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(myconstring);
   string sql = "SELECT flag FROM sms_data_bankasia WHERE flag>=100 AND flag<=109 group by flag";
   MySqlCommand comd = mycon.CreateCommand();
   comd.CommandText = sql;
   mycon.Open();
   MySqlDataReader dtr = comd.ExecuteReader();

   int i = 0;
   while (dtr.Read()) {
      dataValues.Add(dtr.GetInt32(0));

      i++;

      label = new Label();
      label.Name = "label_name" + i;
      label.Size = new Size(60, 20);
      label.Location = new Point(45, 100 + i * 30);
      label.TabIndex = i;
      label.Visible = true;
      this.Controls.Add(label);
   }

   dtr.Close();                                  
}

void PrepareTimers(List<int> _dataValues) {
   foreach (int dataValue in _dataValues) {
      ThreadingTimer timer = new ThreadingTimer(new TimerCallback(TimerAction), dataValue, 0, 2000);
      dict[timer] = label;
   }
}

void TimerAction(object flag) {
   mycon.Open();

   string sql = "SELECT count(flag) FROM sms_data_bankasia where sendingstatus='UPDATED' AND flag = " + (flag.ToString())  + " *2 group by flag";
   MySqlCommand comd = mycon.CreateCommand();
   comd.CommandText = sql;

   MySqlDataReader dtr = comd.ExecuteReader();

   try {
      while (dtr.Read()) {
         ThreadingTimer t = (ThreadingTimer)flag;
         dict[t].Text = dtr[0].ToString() + " program Updated";
      }
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }

   mycon.Close();
}
```

It provides error " Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Threading.Timer' ". What should I do?Any one can help me please?

Comment: On what line do you get the cast error? Also please try to format your code to be easier to read.

Comment: error showed in messagebox.I think error showed in "ThreadingTimer t = (ThreadingTimer)flag;" line @anders.I also write "private Dictionary<ThreadingTimer, Label> dict = new Dictionary<ThreadingTimer, Label>();" for dictionary.

Comment: Why does someone always have to give a -1 for no good reason whatsoever.

Comment: I didn't -1 but the very first sentence of the question is already misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
foreach (int dataValue in _dataValues)
{
    ThreadingTimer timer = new ThreadingTimer(new TimerCallback(TimerAction), dataValue, 0, 2000);
    // dataValue is an int
}
```

takes dataValue as state. The state is provided as your flag. So in

```
void TimerAction(object flag)
```

the cast from object to timer is not valid.

```
ThreadingTimer t = (ThreadingTimer)flag; // flag is an int
```

You can't use the timer as the state of the timer. Maybe use the int as the key for your dictionary?

**Update:**

Instead of declaring

```
private Dictionary<ThreadingTimer, Label> dict = new Dictionary<ThreadingTimer, Label>();
```

you can declare

```
private Dictionary<int, Label> dict = new Dictionary<int, Label>();
```

Instead of

```
dict[timer] = label;
```

you do

```
dict[dataValue] = label;
```

so you can do

```
int t = (int)flag;
dict[t].Text = dtr[0].ToString() + " program Updated";
```

*Untested!*

Comment: Or you could pass both dataValue and the timer object by encapsulating it in an own class.

Comment: The state is passed in in the constructor of the timer - so no way to use the timer itself in the object state.

Comment: Added untested sample for using int

Comment: I use your code but it provide error "Cross-thread operation not valid:Control 'Label-name4' acccessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on " @sascha